# Error Connecting to Gitlab Project - Connection was reset

Tags: connection, visual-studio-2017, gitlab

I used to connect to gitlab project at Visual Studio 2017 and push and pull easily
but today it doesn't do push and pull and shows me the error : "rcv not found . Connection was reset"
I can't find the reason of this error

Comment: It’s probably down, no? Can you access it using your browser? Is it GitLab.com it a privately hosted instance? Contact support.

Comment: Yes I can access from gitlab.com but I can't push or pull in visual studio while I have the access authority to push and pull